# Proper way to set permissions with django and apache2?

Tags: django, permissions, apache2, apache, chmod

I'm using django with wsgi on apache2

I was trying to acess a css file in my site/static/css folder and since the permission was 644, the css file could not be accessed by apache2.

So I chmod 645 on the site/static/css folder and everything was fine.  However, I am worried that granting execution rights to everyone to anything in the css folder could cause security problems.  What is the correct way to tackle this problem, perhaps a way to grant certain permissions using the httpd.conf file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use chown to cause the files to be owned by the same group as apache (www-data?) and then set the permission on the group instead everyone.